# How to prove Dafny count < size

Tags: verification, formal-verification, dafny

I'm currently learning Dafny. I'm totally comfused by lemma and I dont know how to use it. The tutorial is not that helpful. What if I want to prove
`count(a) <= |a|`
how should I do it. Thanks for helping.

```
function count(a: seq<bool>): nat
ensures count(a) <= |a|;
{
   if |a| == 0 then 0 else
   (if a[0] then 1 else 0) + count(a[1..])
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You've already proved it!  You wrote the property you wanted as a postcondition of the function and Dafny verifies it without complaints.  That's it.

You can also use a lemma to prove the property.  Here's an example:

```
function count(a: seq<bool>): nat
{
  if |a| == 0 then 0 else
  (if a[0] then 1 else 0) + count(a[1..])
}

lemma CountProperty(a: seq<bool>)
  ensures count(a) <= |a|
{
}
```

Again, Dafny verifies the lemma without issuing any complaints, so you have proved it!

It is not correct to assume that Dafny will always prove things for you automatically.  Therefore, it's a good idea to learn how to write proofs manually, too.  Here's a manual proof of this property.  Just to make sure Dafny doesn't try to do induction automatically, I used a directive to turn it off (thus making our lives harder than Dafny normally would):

```
lemma {:induction false} CountProperty(a: seq<bool>)
  ensures count(a) <= |a|
{
  // Let's consider two cases, just like the definition of "count"
  // considers two cases.
  if |a| == 0 {
    // In this case, we have:
    assert count(a) == 0 && |a| == 0;
    // so the postcondition follows easily.
  } else {
    // By the definition of "count", we have:
    assert count(a) == (if a[0] then 1 else 0) + count(a[1..]);
    // We know an upper bound on the first term of the addition:
    assert (if a[0] then 1 else 0) <= 1;
    // We can also obtain an upper bound on the second term by
    // calling the lemma recursively.  We do that here:
    CountProperty(a[1..]);
    // The call we just did gives us the following property:
    assert count(a[1..]) <= |a[1..]|;
    // Putting these two upper bounds together, we have:
    assert count(a) <= 1 + |a[1..]|;
    // We're almost done.  We just need to relate |a[1..]| to |a|.
    // This is easy:
    assert |a[1..]| == |a| - 1;
    // By the last two assertions, we now have:
    assert count(a) <= 1 + |a| - 1;
    // which is the postcondition we have to prove.
  }
}
```

A nicer way to write a proof like this is to use a verified calculation, which Dafny calls "the calc statement":

```
lemma {:induction false} CountProperty(a: seq<bool>)
  ensures count(a) <= |a|
{
  if |a| == 0 {
    // trivial
  } else {
    calc {
      count(a);
    ==  // def. count
      (if a[0] then 1 else 0) + count(a[1..]);
    <=  // left term is bounded by 1
      1 + count(a[1..]);
    <=  { CountProperty(a[1..]); }  // induction hypothesis gives a bound for the right term
      1 + |a[1..]|;
    ==  { assert |a[1..]| == |a| - 1; }
      |a|;
    }
  }
}
```

I hope that this gets you started.

Program safely,

Rustan